# CMBright for text only

Tags: fonts

How to use the CMBright font for text only, no into the math mode?
I want CMBright for text and keep default font for math mode...

[image]
with...
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.Stackexchange! Can you give us a small example document to start with? Which document class are you using?

Comment: I use article class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curious choice. However, the bulk of the text font selection in `cmbright.sty` is just three lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% from cmbright.sty
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtl}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
A great theorem
\end{theorem}

Here is the proof
\[
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\biggl(
  \frac{(-1)^{n} x^{2n}}{\Gamma(2n+1)}
  \prod_{k=2}^{\infty}(2k-1)
\biggr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]